# How do I get my command line utility to update one line instead of printing multiple lines?

Tags: ruby, command-line-interface

I'm writing a Ruby command line utility and I'd like it to update one line in the console with new data instead of printing multiple lines of output.  **The effect I'm going for it similar to a console progress bar** you might see when using `wget`.

For instance:

**app.rb**

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby env

data = %w[this is some data]
data.each {|s| puts s}
```

When I run this app it will output the following which spans 4 lines:

```
$ ruby app.rb
this
is
some
data
$
```

I would like the area between [ ] in the following example to show the output, one word at a time.

```
$ ruby app.rb
[ this ]
$
```

Any ideas?

Comment: er.. one word at a time?  Like, you want a human-noticeable delay in between individual words?

Comment: @roippi It doesn't have to be human-noticeable.  Imagine a progress bar.  It updates just one line of the console with new characters.  That's the effect I'm going for.

Comment: Do you want `this is some data` as output?

Comment: @falsetru No. I want: [ this ] then in that **same space**: [ is ] then [ some ] and so on.  All on one line of the console.

Comment: @franksort, I posted an answer. Check it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `\r` (carriage return)  to move the cursor at the start of the line:

```
data = %w[this is some data]
data.each { |s|
  sleep(0.5)
  print "\r%-20s" % s  # `print` instead of `put` to avoid newline.
  # Additional spaces to overwrite remaining characters of previous output
}
puts
```

See [Demo](http://asciinema.org/a/7675).

Comment: Awesome answer.  I love that ASCIIcast too.  I'd give you more points if I could.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use `print s` instead of `puts s` if you want to print them in the same line.